# Apache htaccess - route all requests to index.php except those to certain directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently, my .htaccess file is routing all requests where the file does not exist to index.php. I would like to alter this so that it routes all requests to index.php regardless of whether or not the file exists, except for certain directories/paths. (such as /js, /css, /img)

Here is my current configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with the Google or apache's documentation. Help is much appreciated, as are any general tips on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! ^/css/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! ^/img/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! ^/js/
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There should be no space between the `!` and the regex - this is one argument. (As written this would result in a 500 Internal Server Error, since it's syntactically invalid.) And these _conditions_ should be AND'd, not `OR`'d. But `REQUEST_FILENAME` (the absolute filesystem path) is the wrong server variable to use here, you should use `REQUEST_URI` instead.